# How to generate a library in angular 6 which contains all modules,components,service and use that library in another project

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am new in angular 6 currently, know that I can create a library in angular 6 but when I create library it creates a new module with public_api.ts with other ts files.

I need help for making library using existing components with all dependencies that are used in that component and in my project. eg say I am having userModule so I need to reuse this component as a library in another project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like [`Angular library`](https://angular.io/cli/generate#library) ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. however, I am not able to convert all of the components into a single library and existing modules are not exported in library.